# can i use multiple git accounts in same local system(in Credential Manager)

Tags: git, git-for-windows, git-credential-manager

While I'm trying to fetch branch which is recently created , it shows me `remote: Repository not found.`

That's because of earlier I have added different account in Credential Manager , which is not belonging to the repo which is recently created

My concern is , is it possible to have multiple git accounts in Credential Manager list ?
If anyone knows please answer me, thanks in advance:)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can have multiple credentials in the Global Credential
But you can use a specific credential for the repository itself:

**Two ways to do it:**

**1-**
Config the credential of the project, this is not global:

```
git config credential.${remote}.username yourusername
```

Then, when you push this user will be used not the global.

**2-** Forget old saved credentials:

```
git credential-cache exit
```

After running this command, if you try to push, it will ask you for username and password.